# How do I load the list of a ComboBox from the database?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a sql statement but i am not sure how to implement it so i can use it to populated a combobox in a winforms app.

This is how i had it in a previous app:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Sections" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection%>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT e.DisplayName,  e.ID , e.GUID
            FROM ATable e
            INNER JOIN RootTable re
            ON e.ID = re.TablesID
            AND re.InitID = 1">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

How can i alter this to suite a winforms combobox

----**UPDATE**----

After implementing suggestion below: i am getting an error when i compile stating that the method must be non-generic static class.

Code:

```
public partial class InfoGet : Form
    {
        public InfoGet()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        static string conString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyConnection;Integrated Security=True";
        public static void FillDropDownList(this ComboBox sections_drp, string conString)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using(SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT....", conString))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    sections_drp.ValueMember = "ID";
                    sections_drp.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
                    sections_drp.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Windows Forms application you're going to need to go get it in code, or at least that's what I'm going to recommend. One possible approach is:

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    cnn.Open();
    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapater("SELECT e.DisplayName,  e.ID , e.GUID FROM ATable e INNER JOIN RootTable re ON e.ID = re.TablesID AND re.InitID = 1", cnn))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        comboBox.ValueMember = "ID";
        comboBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
        comboBox.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Now, to make this code reusable, you might build an extension method like this:

```
namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
    public static class ComboBoxExtensions
    {
        public static void Load(this ComboBox comboBox, string sql, string valueMember, string displayMember)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapater(sql, cnn))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    comboBox.ValueMember = valueMember;
                    comboBox.DisplayMember = displayMember;
                    comboBox.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With that extension method it would be pretty easy to use:

```
comboBox.Load("SELECT e.DisplayName,  e.ID , e.GUID FROM ATable e INNER JOIN RootTable re ON e.ID = re.TablesID AND re.InitID = 1",
    "ID",
    "DisplayName");
```

Comment: I am implementing this and i am getting a compile error with `sda.Fill(dt)` stating: that it doesn't exist in current context

Comment: @Masriyah, do you have the appropriate `using` statements at the top of the `.cs` file?

Comment: Nevermind, i found that i had a `;` after the using statement.All good

Comment: I updated my code above and i am getting a non-generic static method error. If you can take a look that will be great.

Comment: @Masriyah, you didn't actually implement what I gave you. It's an extension method that needs implemented in its own `.cs` file. Create a new `.cs` file named `ComboBoxExtensions` and copy the **entire example** I provided you.

Comment: I see, sorry about that i got to excited in trying it out.

Comment: Thanks for the help - it worked great. Now if i want to pass in the selected value from the combo box into another select statement that will populate another combo box based on the id of the first combo box - how could i pass the value into the select statement?

Comment: @Masriyah, give it a shot and then if you're having trouble ask a new question. But make sure you've vetted out some real effort first so that you have some code to show.